# How can I combine the date from one variable with the times of another with MomentJS?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have three variables:

`date = Tue Aug 02 2016 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT);`

`startTime = Thu Jan 01 1970 09:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)`

`endTime = Thu Jan 01 1970 10:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)`

I want to modify the `startTime` and `endTime` to keep their times, but use the date part from `date`. How can I accomplish this with momentjs?

Comment: Maybe you can use moment setter and getters for [`year`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/year/), [`month`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/month/) and [`day`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/date/) or use native js [counterparts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Date.prototype_Methods) (`getFullYear`, `getMonth`, `getDate`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though JohnnyHK's answer is correct... since you asked specifically how to do it using moment.js:

```js
var date = moment(new Date('Tue Aug 15 2016 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)'));
var startTime = moment(new Date('Thu Jan 01 1970 09:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)'));
var endTime = moment(new Date('Thu Jan 01 1970 10:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)'));

console.log("date: " + date.format());
console.log("startTime old: " + startTime.format());
console.log("endTime old: " + endTime.format());

startTime.year(date.year());
startTime.dayOfYear(date.dayOfYear());

endTime.year(date.year());
endTime.dayOfYear(date.dayOfYear());

console.log("startTime new: " + startTime.format());
console.log("endTime new: " + endTime.format());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by using the [get & set](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/) methods of moment:

```
var date = moment(new Date('Tue Aug 02 2016 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)'));
var startTime = moment(new Date('Thu Jan 01 1970 09:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)'));
var endTime = moment(new Date('Thu Jan 01 1970 10:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)'));

var year = date.get('year');
var month = date.get('month');
var day = date.get('day');

startTime.set({ year: year, month: month, day: day });
endTime.set({ year: year, month: month, day: day });

console.log(date.format(), startTime.format(), endTime.format());
```

Output (CST time zone):

```
2016-08-02T19:00:00-05:00 2016-08-02T08:00:00-05:00 2016-08-02T09:00:00-05:00
```

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comment, you can use moment setter and getters for [`year`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/year/), [`month`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/month/) and [`day`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/date/) or use native js [counterparts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Date.prototype_Methods) (`getFullYear`, `getMonth`, `getDate`).

Here a working example showing both solutions:

```js
// Simulating Date object input
var date = moment('2016-08-02T20:00:00').toDate();
var startTime = moment('1970-01-01T09:00:00').toDate();
var endTime = moment('1970-01-01T10:00:00').toDate();

// Using momentjs
var mDate = moment(date);
var mStartTime =  moment(startTime);
mStartTime.year(mDate.year()).month(mDate.month()).day(mDate.day());
console.log(mStartTime.format());

// Pure JavaScript
endTime.setFullYear(date.getFullYear());
endTime.setMonth(date.getMonth());
endTime.setDate(date.getDate());
console.log(endTime.toISOString());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Note that as stated [in the docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/):

> By default, moment parses and displays in local time.

If you need to work with timestamps you can use [moment-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/).